# Sysinternals psexec remotely executed application hangs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, psexec, sysinternals

I'm calling psexec as follows:

`psexec \\10.0.0.1 -i "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"`

notepad++.exe is executed on the remote PC. I can see the application window come up. As soon as I type any characters into notepad++ it hangs.

notepad++.exe does not hang if I execute it locally and type into it.

There's an error in using sysinternals psexec and I can't figure it out. Anybody experience this before?

Both systems are running Windows XP SP3.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

As a side note, psexec works as it should for about 30 minutes. Then it stops working. If I create a new Windows XP user account, it works on that account again for about 30 minutes and then stops working. Neither one of PCs is connected to the internet. They are connected to each other via a cross-over cable.

Comment: Have you contacted SysInternals directly?

Comment: Yup. Haven't heard back yet.